# Inserting multiple custom items into listview

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a class Named Books. The code is here:

```
class Books
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }    
    }
```

The code behind my form looks like this:(Thanks to Omribitan)

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Books> Books { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var query = from p in db.books
                        select new Books
                        {
                            Id = p.id,
                            Name = p.name,
                            description = p.description
                        };

            Books = new ObservableCollection<Books>(query);
            listview1.ItemsSource = Books;

            }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var book = listview1.SelectedItem as Books;
            MessageBox.Show(book.Id.ToString());
        }
```

The XAML looks like this:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listview1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="126,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="BookName"
                      Width="Auto"
               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Publisher"
                      Width="Auto"
               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

With this code, I want to bind my data to the listview. the problem is when I run this code, the second column of my listview is empty.can anyone help me please?

Comment: Don't return an anonymous type. Create a proper data Model or use your existing data model.

Comment: can u be more specific?

Comment: I don't see `mydata` I see an anonymous type

Comment: my data is a linq to sql class.it consists of my tables in database that i have imported them into my project

Answer (score 0):

First of all like @HighCore suggested,Create a proper data type instead of an anonymous type.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Create a collection, like an `ObservableCollection`

```
public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

Add your item's to the collection

```
var db=new mydataDataContext();
var query=from p in db.Book
select new Book{
            Id = p.Id
            Name = P.Name
            Description = P.Description
           };
Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(query);
```

Next, set the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView` to the collection

```
myListView.ItemsSource = Books;
```

Your `ListView` should look something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="BookName"
                      Width="Auto"
               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Publisher"
                      Width="Auto"
               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now, instead of hiding the Id in the first column, You can just access it like this

```
var book = myListView.SelectedItem as Book;
book.Id ....
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry if syntax is incorrect I don't have IDE the check it but it suppose to be good if my memory doesn't lie

Comment: it gives me an error when I'm creating the Observable collection.it says it could not be found.should i use any namespaces?

Comment: I have another question.is this method helpful and fast for tables that have many data in it?

Comment: @user1929674 It depends on what you refer to as "tables that have many data". Either way I think databinding is the way to go, But you can check MSDN Page on [optomizing performance:Data Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx)

Comment: thanks,but i still have the problem in the line         public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; set; } .it says it can not be found :)

Comment: dear Omribitan,thanks for your answer.I fixed the problem I had in creating the ObservableCollection .I should have written using system.collections.objectModel on top of my code.But now I have another porblem in your code. when I run this code it only fills the First column Bookname & the second Column Publisher is empty in the listview

Comment: @user1929674 I had `Description` property in `Book` as int instead of string. I updated my answer. Change it as well and ti should work

Comment: thanks.but it still doesn't show anything in the publisher column (the second column)

Comment: @user1929674 The databinding looks good to me. The only think I can think of is that `Book` items doesn't contain any data in the `Description` property. Debug your code to check it out, If it doesn't work edit your question with your full code and we'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dear Omribitan code,the problem was in the publisher column(the second column) in the xaml. when I changed the DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" to DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding description}" it worked fine.